# Any issues in converting a AutoCAD 2010 DWG to FeatureClass?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, autocad, dwg

I have a small .NET script that uses ArcObjects such as CADtoFeatureClass to convert DWG files to ESRI FeatureClasses.  This standalone program has been working great with DWGs created in previous versions of AutoCAD but I've been told that my code is now not working on DWGs from AutoCAD 2010.  As a temporary solution I can have the users save their DWG files in AutoCAD to previous versions but to permanently fix the problem I need to find out more details.  So does anyone know or has anyone had a similar issue in trying to convert DWG files to FeatureClasses using these types of ArcObjects on AutoDesk 2010 DWG files?

Thanks for any advice.

best regards,

Comment: your question is confusing. it worked on 2010 version but it doesn't. ?? My experience with the cadtofeatureclass is that it creates feature classes that are extremely hard to utilize. there are much better methods of conversion from cad to gis data.

Comment: I stated in my question that it works on "previous versions". Sorry

Comment: no problem tsall good

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with AutoCAD 2010 and not 2012?

Comment: Also, can you post an offending dwg file?  I've got some dwg import tools I've written and would like to see how they handle it.

Answer (score 2):

I used the cad to feature class a few versions ago. I think 9.1 or 9.2.
I was less than impressed.

I use Autocad map which has an export directly in it.
The export from map allowws me to select specific layers or objects to export. I can select many options for attribute export, and can re-project to any crs or keep the same.
All of these options can be saved to an ipf file which will load the same settings on another export or import.
BTW: FME is the originator of all of the autodesk export import functionality and works also for these formats.

When creating feature classes with arcmap it made many obscure feature classes out of what it thought was an object. (which it wasn't) and included it's own naming scheme for attributes (which again I am not sure even where it got the attribute from).

That is my take.

I have seen a lot about OGR (in GDAL), And if you have access to autocad map 3d or civil design 3d (autodesk products). I can give you a brief walkthrough to get something out.